# jQuery: Click event to change input text

Tags: jquery

I'm puzzled why my very easy script doesn't work. I want to write text into an input field when pressing a button, simple as that :)

Right now I have this:

```
<input type="button" class="plan-button" id="button15"  value="충전" />
```

and my jQuery:

```
$('#button15').click(function() {
  $('input').val($('input').val() + 'sample text');
});
```

Without the click event, using only this line:

```
 $('input').val($('input').val() + 'more text');
```

This works fine. So the problem is the click event? I triple checked for errors... Help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the rest of the page... I excluded some of the identical table rows to make it easier to read.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#button15').click(function() {
  $('input').val($('input').val() + 'more text');
 });

});
</script>
<table id="mytable" border="0" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="box"> <input type="button" class="plan-button" id="button15"  value="충전" /></div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This will work, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Can you provide some more of you code? As said before, it will work this way.

Comment: Works fine, perhaps show more of the page contents so we can see where the problem is http://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/rLvNoX

Comment: I just tried it in your code pen and it works. It is within a joomla page and the input which I want to write in is in a different module, maybe that is the problem.
Very strange though that as soon as I remove the click event, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the click, you don't say which input you want. If it's all, you need to do an each like this:

```
$('#button15').click(function() {
  $('input').each( function(){ 
      $.(this).val( $(this).val() + 'sample text')
  });
});
```

If you want add 'sample text' only in specific input, add a class like this:

```
 $('#button15').click(function() {
  $('.change').each( function(){ 
      $.(this).val( $(this).val() + 'sample text')
  });
 });
```